# why mongodb converting python dictionary to object

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, python-dataclasses, data-class

```
@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Metadata:
    key = None
    data = None

def some_method():
   raw_data = 
        {
          "key": "ZEl",
          "data": [
            {
              "type": "rich_text",
              "elements": [
                {
                  "type": "text",
                  "text": "Some text"
                  "elements" : [ 
                    { "type":"text_section",
                       "text":"inner text"
                    }
                   ]
                }
              ]
            }
           ]
         }
     metadata = Metadata.from_dict(raw_data)
     print(metdata.to_dict())  # print data as expected
     mongo_connector.collection.insert_one(metadata.to_dict())
```

Here i am using `pymongo` to interact with the MongoDB. This dictionary is getting written into mongodb correctly but it is converting inner `elements` key to `Object`. I tried to use `asdict(), to_dict()` of `dataclasses` but nothing worked. While i print the data via `print` it data looks consistant but writing into mongo, it is holding some another shape.

Output of Mongo

```
{
        _id: ObjectId("3b8a25c03f011d64a77f015d"),
        key: 'ZEl',
        data: [
            {
                type: 'rich_text',
                elements: [
                 {
                   type: 'text',
                   text: 'Some text',
                   elements: [ [Object] ]
                 }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I could not understand this behaviour of converting inner `elements` to `[ [Object`] ]`

Comment: How exactly are you looking at the data? It’s probably just a matter of the tool used to output that data.

Comment: i used mongosh to to look at the data

Comment: Try some other tool, or explicitly access the nested object directly, and you’ll probably see it just fine.

Comment: Why can't you just insert the dictionary into mongo ,e.g. `mongo_connector.collection.insert_one(raw_data)`?

Comment: @BellyBuster, the above example is just a sample for actual problem. The data to be written into mongo is coming from a `dataclass` thatswhy i depicted that